# How to detect whether there is other app playing music background?

Tags: java, android, audio

I am developing a Video App, and I need to know whether is any BGM playing?
I tried to use AudioManager.isMusicActive(), but it didn't work, because when I play my video, this method always returns true(I guess it detects my app).

> In a word, I need to know BGM playing in other App, not Mine.

Comment: If you're [requesting audio focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus) properly, then they'll stop when you start and vice versa. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, I'm using requestAudioFocus(). I'm doing this, My video can play under 0 volume, with BGM playing out. It means there are 2 sounds playing together, one is my mute video, the other is BGM. My problem is I want to know exactly BGM's info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've solved this problem by detecting other app's music every time before my music is going to start. 
Because befeore your music is playing, if AudioManager.isMusicActive() returns true, then it means BGM is playing. 
Something like this,

```
public void start() {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) weak_context.get().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    boolean check = am.isMusicActive();
    playMyMusic();
}
```